# Stop .click() from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to stop .click() from firing when a condition has been met? My code looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// stocheaza ordinea corecta a imaginilor
var correctOrder = $("#puzzle > img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
}).get();

// amesteca imaginile
var x = $("#puzzle > img").remove().toArray();
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var bi = x[i];
    var bj = x[j];
    x[i] = bj;
    x[j] = bi;
    }
$("#puzzle").append(x);

// event onclick pe 2 piese sa'si schimbe pozitia    
$("img.element").click(function(){
    if (clickCount == 0)
    {
        imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        lastImgId = $(this).attr("id");
        clickCount++;
    }
    else {
        $("#"+lastImgId).attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src",imgSrc);
        clickCount = 0;

// returneaza ordinea imaginilor curente
        var currentOrder = $("#puzzle > img").map(function() {
          return $(this).attr("src");
        }).get();

// compara ordinea imaginilor curente cu cea corecta
        if (currentOrder.compare(correctOrder)) 
        updateBubble(2);
    }
});
});
```

I need to stop `$("img.element").click(function(){ }` when this condition `if (currentOrder.compare(correctOrder))` has been met. At the moment this .click() function allow me to click on 2 images and change their positions but `updateBubble(2);` is the final feedback and i must cannot change images when this feedback is given. Thx

Comment: Just surround the whole body of the click handler with the condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change little bit like this with use of `.on()` to bind the event and `.off()` to unbind the event:

```
$("img.element").on('click', function(){ // use with .on() handler
```

and here to unbind the event:

```
if (currentOrder.compare(correctOrder)) 
    updateBubble(2);
    $(this).off('click'); // use .off() to unbind the click event
```

Comment: This code is close to the truth but i still can move few pieces if i force click.

Comment: Solved: $("img.element").off("click"); is the correct form

Comment: And i really appreciate ur help!

Comment: Thanks too.Glad to be here ! ^_^ I have alot of questions :D Now I have to do drag and drop the puzzle pieces to the right and drop to the left where I have other pieces that match those on the right. The problem is that my page is scaleable and if i drop pieces will be a total mess.I havea read about offset() but im sure ill need help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $("img.element").click(function(){
 if(currentOrder.compare(correctOrder))//return and do not execute click event code if condition
  return;

 //rest click event code here
 });
```

Comment: Who downvoted this...this is exactly what you should do

Answer (score 2):

the general way to stop the click from firing is to use preventDefault, like this:

```
("img.element").click(function(event){
    if(condition) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only prevent OTHER click events higher up the DOM tree from being fired. It will not prevent the rest of the code in the function from firing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

might do what you're looking for....

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(condition){
return false;
}
```

That will stop the other part of the function from firing!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $("img.element").click(function(){
 if(currentOrder.compare(correctOrder) ){
   return false; // return and prevent further listener.
 }

if (clickCount == 0)
    {
        imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        lastImgId = $(this).attr("id");
        clickCount++;
    }
    else {
        $("#"+lastImgId).attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src",imgSrc);
        clickCount = 0;

// returneaza ordinea imaginilor curente
        var currentOrder = $("#puzzle > img").map(function() {
          return $(this).attr("src");
        }).get();

// compara ordinea imaginilor curente cu cea corecta
        if (currentOrder.compare(correctOrder)) 
        updateBubble(2);
    }


 });
```

Comment: This look good but i cant change images from start...i need to happen this block after i change images several times (its a puzzle shuffled and i must discover the whole picture by changeing images) . When i discover the whole picture i get updateBubble(2); feedback and stop firing click